# Why can't I access members declared in my class while overloading "<<" operator?

Tags: c++, overloading

i have a little issue here that i can't handle. So, i declared my class Sir like this:

```
typedef unsigned int Uint;
typedef vector<Uint> TVint;
typedef vector<Uint>::const_iterator TIterator;

class Sir
{
protected:
    Uint _count;
    TVint _elements;
public:
    ...
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Sir &sir)
        {
            for(size_t i = 0; i < sir._count; i++)
            {
                out<<"[" << i << "]" << "   " << sir._elemente[i]<<endl;               
            }
        }
};
```

It says that cannot access protected member declared in class. What am I missing??

Comment: `sir._elemente` looks like it should be `sir.elements`, but othwerwise you're not missing anything, the code is fine.

Comment: It appears you want to make it a non-member friend (since the `friend` keyword is present), yet by defining it inline it's actually implemented as a member function (meaning that the `friend` keyword is unnecessary).  What is the _exact_ error message the compiler is giving you?

Comment: @Chad: The `friend` keyword is exactly what makes that a non-member function.

Comment: i've put the definition inline here just to save some rows...the function is declared in my .h file and defined in my .cpp file.

Comment: @Chad I don't think so... http://ideone.com/qJSugE

Comment: @user3033831 Show the real code, then.

Comment: @Chad, the error message is:  error C2248: Sir::_elemente' : cannot access protected member declared in class 'Calcule::Sir'

Comment: @K-ballo interesting :)  I didn't realize the friend function worked as a modifier in that manner.

Comment: It compiles fine for me on GCC 4.8 after I corrected the obvious mistakes (changed _elemente to _elements and added the missing return). I think your problem must be elsewhere, and you lost something relevant when you "cleaned up" the code to post it here. Please post a complete program that you have confirmed shows the error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo, you should use `_elements` in the overloaded `<<` instead of `_elemente`. and you should return something from that method:

```
friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &out, const Sir &sir)
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sir._count; i++)
    {
        out<<"[" << i << "]" << "   " << sir._elements[i] <<endl;
                                       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    return out;
  //^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd37365a1887c8b6)